# Adding paragraph tags around each line in html textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

I'm trying to make text input in a textarea as easy as possible for the user, without them needing to know any code or have to deal with wysiwyg formatting. It's just text.
But since the text, when shown on the page, will be shown in html, it would be great for there to be 'p' tags around each line.

Right now I've tried this:

```
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['content']);

    $paragraphs = explode("\n", $content);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($paragraphs); $i++)
    {
        $paragraphs[$i] = '<p>' . $paragraphs[$i] . '</p>';
    }
    $content = implode('', $paragraphs);
```

But this is putting the `<p></p>` tags around EVERYTHING - one at the beginning of the post, and one at the end, ignoring all returns.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, this encodes certain things - from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

> **escapestr**
>
> The string to be escaped.
>
> Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

So any `\n`'s will be escaped.

You could change it round to do the replacement first...

```
$paragraphs = explode("\n", $_POST['content']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($paragraphs); $i++)
{
    $paragraphs[$i] = '<p>' . $paragraphs[$i] . '</p>';
}
$content = implode('', $paragraphs);
```

BUT you should also be using prepared statements, so you shouldn't need to call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` at all.

Comment: I haven't really gotten around to learning to use prepared statements yet... (been coding in php for about a month now) - but I'll look into it. Thanks for the quick response.

For now, until I get the prepared statements down, I've rearranged the code and it works great. Thanks!